# Question with .find and a return value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm fairly new to rails (only about a month's experience), so this may be trivial. In my app, if I call

```
<%= Group.find(:all).each do |g| %>
   <p><%= g.name %></p>
<%= end %>
```

it prints out all of the groups' names correctly. However, afterwards, it returns all of them (with the hexcodes, and stuff). I figure that's because `.find` returns everything you have it iterate over. Anyways - on to my question: **Is .find the wrong method, or how do I go about iterating over every Group, without returning them afterwards?**

I would appreciate any help or insight you all have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're doing something like

```
<%= Group.find(:all).each do |g| %>
   <p><%= g.name %></p>
<%= end %>
```

That would print the return value of the whole statement. Instead, do this

```
<% Group.find(:all).each do |g| %>
   <p><%= g.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

That wouldn't print the returned value.

Sidenote: `Group.find(:all)` is the same as `Group.all`

Comment: Hey Dogbert, thank you! Is it just me, or is the code in your second example the same as the code in the first example?

Comment: I should've highlighted it :) I changed `<%=` to `<%` in two places.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much! Once I can accept the answer, I will.